# Printing entries in a Collection

Tags: excel, vba, collections, output

I have a Collection containing x amount of items. I simply need the contents of that Collection to be output into an Excel column.

```
For Each item In myCollection
'Insert code here

Next item
```

Any idea how I can do this?

Comment: It depends the type of item in the collection. So to begin with, add `Debug.Print "Item type: " & TypeName(item)` within the For loop, then from the immediate window, research on the object properties. If you do record a macro and go type some text in some cell, stop record and you should have an idea of how to put value in a cell.

Comment: Please have a look at my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the starting row or column from 1, to whatever you want. Also you can insert into cells by incrementing columns by replacing 'r = r + 1' with 'c = c + 1'.

Note: Change "Sheet1" to whatever your worksheet name is, this is just the default name I used since I don't know the name of your actual worksheet.

```
Dim r As Integer
Dim c As Integer
r = 1 'Row 1
c = 1 'Column A
For Each item In myCollection
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(r, c).Value = item
    'Increment Row by 1
    r = r + 1
Next item
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you!

Comment: For the record the other answer below is more than likely way more efficient. However I wouldn't worry about it unless you are having more than 100 items or so in your collection.

Answer (score 2):

This is one of the reasons why a Dictionary object is superior to the Collection object.

With Collections you must loop through the entire collection object to retrieve all of the values.

With Dictionaries you can retrieve all of the values in one go, which is a tremendous speed boon when writing to a worksheet. Writing one cell at a time is one of the most inefficient things you can do in Excel.

So here is how to convert to using Dictionaries. Note the last line. The entire dictionary is written to the range in one go:

```
Sub zaanwar()

    Dim myDictionary As Object

    Set myDictionary = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")

    With myDictionary
        .Item("key1") = "val1"
        .Item("key2") = "val2"
        .Item("key3") = "val3"
        .Item("key4") = "val4"
    End With

    [a1:d4] = Application.Transpose(myDictionary.Items)

End Sub
```

Comment: Cool Tip! I will use that Transpose Method Next time! Note: If the user wants _intellisense_ for the Dictionary Object, they need to add the `Microsoft Scripting Runtime` Reference to their project.